# Use a Dynamic Range for Chart Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Is there any way to do this other than using an API?

[image]

It seems like you can't specify the range of a chart with a formula.

I've tried name ranges too - does anyone know a work around?

Comment: Why not apply the formula to the data itself and then reference it in the chart? You could use a QUERY for example.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately this one is not possible. google sheets (up to this date) does not support formulas in input field of charts. the only thing you can do is to query/filter your dataset on some separate hidden sheet and then construct chart from there.